# Error itms-90035 - Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, appstore-approval

I have developed a phonegap application which is running absolutely fine on iPhone. Now, I want to submit the app to the appstore. Following is the procedure I am following to submit my app:

1. Open Xcode and archive the project
2. Click on validate (which is successful)
3. Click on Submit to appstore (which is where I am getting the following error)

[image]

Until yesterday night, I wasn't even getting this error and today morning, I archive the project and I get this error. Not sure what the issue is.

This is the final stage which is stopping me from submitting the app and is very frustrating, I tried to search for the same error code on the stackoverflow forum and I could not find one single post which is exactly of the same error code as mine, which is very strange.

Please help :)

Comment: Are you sure, your code signing settings are proper?

Comment: I am not sure about it, how do I check that ? Can you please guid me with that ?

Comment: Nikhil I am getting the same error too since this morning. I just tried to "validate" an old version of my app that was ALREADY APPROVED AND UPLOADED successfully. Other than the expected errors I'm expecting (version already exists in AppStore, version of my application is closed for modification since it is released, etc.) I keep getting this ITMS-90035. I have also validated that my certificates are not revoked (from Apple's developer center). I will update you upon my findings later on today, and will monitor this post to hear yours. Thanks :)

Comment: Same here, yesterday i  have submitted many builds without errors. Codes and settings have not changed.

Comment: I've revoked the certificate. and created new distribution cert. problem still persists..

Comment: same here, is an Apple bug?

Comment: Seems like an apple bug, not sure as of now because of no concrete evidence :(

Comment: Solved for me deleting the pod 'Analytics', '~> 1.2' ARGGG...

Comment: Nikhil solved by removing .sh file from my target as suggested in below answer.

Comment: Will Crittercism work after removing .sh file?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, but in my case, it's not a .sh file, it is a .js file from one of my library i'm using inside my application

Comment: @Frank Some where in the answers below, someone has mentioned that they as well faced the same issue and resolved it by remove that particular js file. Have a look, hope it helps.

Comment: @NikhilRao The .js file in the error message is a file that I actually use in my application, I cannot remove it, but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I had the same problem, turns out that one of my libraries installed via bower includes a `.sh` file, which is not needed. I have just deleted the file and everything has been uploaded successfully.

Seems like that Apple now enforces developers to have `.sh` files in their apps signed. As Cordova/Phonegap app don't need any of them, you can safely delete them.

Comment: This is the only correct answer. 

You don't need to delete the file, by the way. Just exclude it from your targets.

Comment: I only have one .sh file in my project under platforms > ios > cordova > lib > copy-www-build-step.sh. Is this the one I'm supposed to delete? Or only if there is two? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!!!  This is the correct answer.  In my case it was the Crittercism dsym_upload.sh file that was getting copied into my bundles by CocoaPods, which has become a swear word over at my company.

Comment: I have Crittercism included via CocoaPods and it has dsym_upload.sh script which causes this error too. So for now I just commented out this line in Pods-resources.sh file: install_resource "CrittercismSDK/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh"

Comment: If crittercism is you issue and you are using cocoa pods try the fix I added as a comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816930/not-able-to-upload-application-because-of-sh-file-of-crittercism/29826481#29826481

Comment: it can be anything, delete it in copy bundle resources.

Comment: In my case it was a .sh inside karma javascript test runner

Comment: Mine was on "/XMPPFramework/Vendor/libidn/build-libidn.sh"

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me after updating to the latest Xcode (6.3.1). It's not just .sh files, as I was getting these errors about node scripts. It appears that ANY file that starts with #!/usr/bin/env will cause these errors. I was able to cause arbitrary errors by adding a #! to a random file.

Temporarily deleting the #!/usr/bin/env directive from the top of the files will work but you'll want a better long-term solution :)

You'll have to fix it by dealing with each script file case-by-case for what makes sense in your project.

As noted above this could be a temporary problem on Apple's side, not necessarily related to Xcode version.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: I managed to avoid this error by **removing my projects .sh files from my target**.

So far I'd say that's a bug on Apple's side.

I submitted an app yesterday without any issue, rejected it today to submit a slightly altered binary today, but like you I'm now encountering the same error.
I thought it was related to `Xcode6.3.1` because I installed it this morning so I installed `Xcode 6.3.0` again but the error remained. Then I checking everything thoroughly:

- Certificates
- Provisioning Profiles
- iTunes connect application status

But no success so far.

The fact a "itms-90035" Google search returns only 1 result makes me think that may be some temporary incident.

Comment: I did whatever you did and I am completely of the same opinion as yours. Completely agree, fingers crossed, hopefully they resolve this issue sooner.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I got this error because the app display name had a special character in it. It escapes me why proper error messages cannot be generated.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, the problem appears to be due to including files named "upload-dsym.sh" in the app bundle.  Here are the steps I took to get past this error:
Went to the project settings in Xcode and selected the "Target" app icon.
Selected the Build Phases tab.
Clicked on "Copy Bundle Resources"
Looked for a file being copied named "upload-dsym.sh".
I removed that file and then the upload went fine.

Comment: The process described in this answer is the detailed path to removing the *.sh file from the signed app. In my case it was `buildtime.sh` produced by the Worklight environment. As this is a relatively "new" issue, to-date, it appears as though Apple have indeed changed something in the submittal process...

Answer (score 3):

It has something to do with included `.sh files`, not that obvious indeed.

---

### In our case, it was the AudioKit library. README says:

> In most cases, when building for iOS or tvOS, regardless of how you install the framework, you will need to add a run phase to your project's target with the following script:
>
> `"$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH/AudioKit.framework/fix-framework.sh"`

---

Sometimes you don't see them directly in your target's `build phases`. Some of the *3rd party libraries* can cause this error because they are dealing with `.sh files` as well.

Check your *3rd party libraries/pods* `README`'s files for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. Then I delete the .sh file. And I submit my app again. Successful!

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been resolved in CrittercismSDK CocoaPods 5.2.0 : https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/CrittercismSDK/5.2.0/CrittercismSDK.podspec.json

You may either upgrade to sdk 5.2.0 or delete the file and remove the following lines from the Pods-resources.sh file:

```
    if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then 
install_resource "CrittercismSDK/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh" 
fi 
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]]; then 
install_resource "CrittercismSDK/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh" 
fi
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had a very similar problem today and solved it.

> ERROR ITMS-90035: "Invalid Signature. A sealed resource is missing or invalid. The binary at path [MyNiftyApp.app/MyNiftyApp] contains an invalid signature. [...]"

We are using Jenkins-CI for the build process together with the xcode-plugin.
When I reviewed the jenkins build log I found this error message:

```
file added: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/RELEASE_STAGE_my-nifty-app/build/MyNiftyApp.app/MyNiftyApp.app
file modified: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/RELEASE_STAGE_my-nifty-app/build/MyNiftyApp.app/Assets.car
]
Codesign check fails : /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/RELEASE_STAGE_my-nifty-app/build/MyNiftyApp.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
```

After searching for that Assets.car I found this post:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21253
The User had a similar problem, could solve it by **deactivating** the following plugin option "XCode -> General Build Settings -> **Generate Archive?** " (it was true before, now it's false).

At least this solved the problem on our side - maybe it will guide you to the correct direction.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by simply removing the "binary" file(s) in the error.

For you its www/js/release.sh.

For me it was two redundant bower-files, a .sh-file and a .js-file that was located under a "bin"-folder (maybe thats why it thought it was a binary?).

On a side-note, it seems that you could still continue the upload process by just clicking Send after being presented with the errors in Application Loader.

Answer (score 1):

I received this same error when I tried to upload my app using ApplicationLoader 3.0.  Upgrading to ApplicationLoader 3.1 (i.e. the latest), fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I use Application Loader, version `3.1 (670)` and I still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In the platforms directory run:

```
grep -r '#!/usr/' *
```

This will show you all the files that can be executed. Typically this would include .sh and node files.

From the results find the files that are in your project folder (e.g. my project folder was platforms/ios/www/*) and delete them leave the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. I was writing a bug on the myApp.app/myApp
Decision:
Look for files that start with special characters or characters other than English. I found, deleted and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue using both xcode 6.3.1 and 6.4 beta. Mine said it was my main.o file. I looked in the copy bundle resources and for some reason my project's main file was there. I removed it and archived it again to send up to itunes connect for testflight and it uploaded fine. Took me 3 hrs to figure out it was that stupid file. Home this helps. Seems you need to really pay attention to what your sending up in that "Copy Bundle Resources" in build phases. Whatever file its telling you is a problem remove taht from this area and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the error when submitting a re-signed ipa file. Turns out I had looked at the application package in Finder, and it had created a .DS_Store file (this was after re-signing with `codesign`, which would have complained if the file were present at the time of signing).

After removing the .DS_Store file, the upload succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command (in mac) : `codesign --verify -vvvv  <your_application>.app`

sample:

```
codesign --verify -vvvv project.app
project.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
file missing: /Users/iHTCboy/workspace/Payload/project.app/.DS_Store
```

Looks like that have a hidden file .DS_Store inside the assets of my app.
Kindly find and remove it and try again.

that is work for me