# XCode Error itms-90035 - Invalid signature?

Tags: ios, xcode, bower, google-chrome-app

I've been building with Chrome-Mobile-Apps for the last few weeks in XCode with no problems until this morning, where I'm getting this `Erorr itms-90035` when I try to submit my archive to the App Store. It will validate fine, but when I try to submit -- nada. Here is the error I get:

[image: xcode error itms-90035]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788601/error-itms-90035-xcode) thread that has the same issue, but the highest rated solution is not working for me. The file it points to in my erorr is a Unix Executable File that when I run doesn't do anything and I'm not sure if it's safe to delete. I searched by project for `.sh` files but only found one that is required to run the project. I'm not sure where the error is actually coming from? Any assistance? I'm incredibly confused here. I think apple changed something on their end.

**edit** Yes I am aware that there is another thread on this topic, that's where I first checked, as I said in my post. Unfortunately, the solutions in that thread are not related to my issue. I only have one `.sh` file in my project and it is required to copy the contents of my www folder w/ cordova to the iOS project, I think. If I remove the file my project will not build.

**edit2** the only things in my `copy bundle resources` bit in the `build phases` tab are all of my icon/splash image files and `MainViewController.xib`. I don't think these are the issue

Comment: Have you checked here?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859996/error-itms-90035

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete the .sh file under your bower components folder. So just follow the instruction path for your binary file, find the file end with .sh and delete it. You should be good to go. Apple recently enforce this, and it is super annoying.

Refer the original solution working for me here: [Error itms-90035 - Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788601/error-itms-90035-xcode)

Comment: I don't have a .sh file in my bower components folder, I've tried searching and nada. The file in the error is pointing to a unix executable file

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was with git. I removed .git file by running rm -rf .git
and the app got submitted successfully.

Comment: Don't have git on this project! Not sure what's going on..

Comment: Check Copy resources path. I found a file which was 'do-git' and i deleted it and it worked. Make sure you check all the files in it, and remove unnecessary one's.

Answer (score 0):

A similar thing happened to me.
I was using phonegap build for creating my .ipa file.

My Tip is to look at the path of the file mentioned in the error message.
When I looked at it it seemed to refer to a file that was not part of my project at all.

It turned out that my build process did not do a proper cleaning of the folder into which it copied the files to be zipped and sent to phonegap build - so that old files where still included.

Adding a proper cleanup initial step to my build proccess fixed the issue right away.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using crittercsim version prior to 5.2.0, it has a file name dsym_upload.sh which is also causing problem, if that is the case, please update your crittercism source.

Answer (score -1):

For me the error was related to having a file in 'Copy Bundle Resources' that did not belong there. Reading other threads it appears to be a common theme. It's not so much of a particular type of file but more about 'any' file that shouldn't be there.  If you go into your app target/Build Phases/Copy Bundle Resources...I expect you will find a file that does not belong there (with the name 'marked'? - assuming you have all your proper Code Signing authorities). Remove the file from the Copy Bundle Resources...(not necessarily from your project - you may need that file for you App to work)...just get it out of 'Copy Bundle Resources'. If you are still uncertain of what file is causing your problem, try Archiving and Validating your App. Although, it will Validate fine it will indicate a file with Zero Entitlements. That file should be the problem.

Comment: Can you please break up that answer in paragraphs for better readability? Markdown requires an empty line between paragraphs.

Comment: When I check the Copy Bundle Resources section of xcode there is nothing in there relating to the file it says it's having a problem with, just my icons and splash images and MainViewController.xib, which sounds important and I'm not sure I should remove.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by just removing the entire unix executable file. My project didn't need it apparently. Not a great solution (actually the worst) but it works!