# App Store error ITMS-90035 - .js file is not signed

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, cordova, app-store

This error is similar to many that others have been citing, with a different spin. I get the error, "Invalid signature. Code object is not signed at all. The binary at path [.../iscroll.js] contains an invalid signature. Make sure you have signed your application with a distribution certificate..." and so on, similar to these problems:

[Error itms-90035 - Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788601/error-itms-90035-xcode)

[XCode Error itms-90035 - Invalid signature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807784/xcode-error-itms-90035-invalid-signature)

However, I haven't seen any so far that reference problems with javascript errors, so I wanted to post this question which I'll answer below with my fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix I found that worked right away was to remove the assets folder that is created by Cordova. If your build is properly created, only 5 files are needed:

- index.html file
- codova.js
- assets/all.min.css
- assets/all.min.js
- assets/app.js

With just this small subset of files, the .js code signing errors disappear, along with any other errors you might be getting from .sh files, etc.

NOTE: We use minified code, and this list is for minified compiles.