# XCode - Invalid Signature. Code not signed at all. ITMS-90035

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, swift2

I recently made some changes to my iOS app.

Now I want to push the new files to iTunes Connect and I keep getting "ITMS-90035 Invalid Signature. Code is not signed at all."

I found answers to similar questions here on StackOverflow but I there was no solution provided that worked for me.

Here is what I tried:

- I tried to reactivate my certs / provisioning profiles to make sure they are valid and configured for deployment
- I checked for .sh / .git files as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807784/xcode-error-itms-90035-invalid-signature) - but couldn't find any
- I checked my build settings as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29859996/error-itms-90035)
- I checked for external libs but I'm only using GoogleMobileAds and GoogleAnalytics - both worked in my last submit (this issue was mentioned multiple times with different external libs)

Any idea where to search? Sadly iTunes Connect doesn't give any feedback about which file makes the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed you tagged this under `swift2`. Are you using a beta Xcode to build and submit to the App Store? That's not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

Crazily, I was able to fix this by unchecking the `Include Bitcode ?` checkbox when uploading via Xcode 8.1 (8B62). `ENABLE_BITCODE` is set to `YES` everywhere in my project, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Will report back once it's sorted.