# Not able to upload application because of .sh file of Crittercism

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect, itunes, crittercism

We are using Crittercism SDK since last 2 years and we are successfully able to upload application. Since last 2 days, we are not able to upload application with Crittercism because of dsym_upload.sh file.

Anyone getting same issue...!!!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This issue is resolved in CrittercismSDK 5.2.0 CocoaPods spec: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/CrittercismSDK/5.2.0/CrittercismSDK.podspec.json

If you don't want to upgrade to 5.2.0, then just delete the file
and remove these lines from the Pods-resources.sh file

if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Debug" ]]; then
  install_resource "CrittercismSDK/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh"
fi
if [[ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ]]; then
  install_resource "CrittercismSDK/CrittercismSDK/dsym_upload.sh"
fi

Comment: The pods-resources.sh file is a generated file, hence modifying this will be overridden the next time pod install is executed.
I suggest upgrading or making the change reproducable like I suggested in my other answer.

Comment: Best Answer ever, i solved problem with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

That shell script should not be part of the app bundle as it's only used while building (if it's anything like the Crashlytics version then it just uploads the `.dsym` files to their server so crash logs can be symbolicated for you).

Find the *Build Phase Copy Files* step that is copying it to the app bundle and remove the script from that step.

**EDIT** Please note that the script still needs to be **executed** during a build in order to upload debug symbols, however it does not need to be copied to the app bundle.

Comment: So, if I will remove .sh file from Build Phase then will it allow me to upload application on iTunes ?

Comment: Try it and see. it can't hurt.

Comment: Okay.. Thanks for your comments Let me try and check after removing from Build Phases, I am able to get crash log or not.

Comment: @Wezly, we have tried to run application with out .sh file of Crittercism. but we are not able to get crash log.

Comment: @iPhonedeveloper. The `.sh` file cannot be executable as part of the iOS app as there is no shell and its name suggests its role is to upload the `.dsym` file and debug symbols are not shipped with the iOS app, so removing the script from the app bundle will not break crash reports.  Please note I never suggested stopping the script from being executed, only from being copied to the app bundle.

Comment: We have removed file from application and add dysm file in Crittercism. So, we are able to get crash log successfully. @Wezly Thanks for supporting us.

Comment: I didn't do anything, but no probs.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue using cocoa pods.
As a temporary workaround I have put the following into my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
    ...
    system('perl -pi.back -e "s/install_resource \"CrittercismSDK\/CrittercismSDK\/dsym_upload.sh\"//" "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"')
end
```

What it does is it removes the line where the dsym_upload.sh is copied as a resource to what in the end ends up in you .app file

Comment: Helped me! But I needed to change `"Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods-resources.sh"`by `"Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ProjectName/Pods-ProjectName-resources.sh"`.

Answer (score 0):

I've also met this kind of problem. In my case, it was caused by putting space and special character in the package file name (.app file). After changing the name (removed space and special character) I was able to sign and upload application without any problems.